# Rail 5.1 - ActionController::UnknownFormat with AJAX form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

My chat boxes input looks like this:

```
<div class="chatboxinput">
  <%= form_with(url: [@conversation, @message], id: "conversation_form") do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_area :body, class: "chatboxtextarea", "data-cid" => @conversation.id %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

As you can see, just a basic form_with (omitted the remote: true because it's default).

When this form is submitted like this:

```
$('#conversation_form').submit();
```

It's supposed to submit through AJAX and then run a javascript file.

The code ran when that form is submitted looks like this:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_users_user!

  def create

    #Do stuff here

    respond_to :js
  end
end
```

The `#Do stuff here` code is getting executed perfectly but instead of rendering the file `messages/create.js.erb`, it just returns the error

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

And

```
    respond_to :js
  end
```

The terminal shows:

```
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 13ms (ActiveRecord: 3.7ms)

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):

app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:22:in `create'
```

I've looked through every single related stack overflow thread and have no idea why this is going on.

Also, I noticed that when the call is sent the terminal shows `Processing by MessagesController#create as HTML` isn't this supposed to be as JS instead?

Comment: It's supposed to be JS, otherwise it'll wait a HTML response, you can add `remote: true` and do Rails handle that, or to send the form yourself by adding that JS part, or to set the route for that action as JS by default.

Comment: @SebastianPalma with `form_with`- `remote:true` is default. I also inspected the form and the remote tag is there. I'll try setting the route for that action as JS by default. Thanks

Comment: I had the exact same setup / problem. My fix was to explicitly say `local: false` in the `form_with` - even though it should be default!